# Cloudstack agent is not running

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and during cloudstack installation I am having a problem with service cloudstack-agent. It started OK but showing status cloudstack-agent is not running. please do suggest.

[image]

Comment: Please give more detail to your question. What steps did you follow in your installation? What environment are you running on? What are the logs showing?

Answer (score 0):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/KVM+agent+debug , change the log level and provide log  to debug